# How can I tell if a program (in this case Jitsi Meet Electron) has bad-enough vulnerablities making it unsafe for current use and/or protect myself?

Tags: vulnerability

I'm uneasy that Jitsi Meet (videoconferencing stack) is Chrome-first (bug relating to other browsers are fixed later) and dislike Chrome for privacy reasons. Jitsi has an Electron desktop web-wrapper though which I want to try, but I'm just paranoid that not enough devs are verifying its code, and that a hacker could find something, especially if the user's in a work/business environment, even if that user prefers open-source to apps like Zoom. My associates and I are currently not ready for everyone to switch to a distro like Qubes (not to mention that Qubes has no commercial support feature).

Comment: Unfortunately we're not here to provide an application vetting service

Comment: If you truly care so much about supporting ‘x’ for application ‘y’ that is open source hire a developer to do the support for you. (Either yourself or through a support program). Jitsi meet is chrome first because chrome has the best webrtc support and dev tools (currently) the next one they usually look at is Firefox and than possibly others. Webrtc is not so unified as for example javascript is these days so writing code for it is quite difficult, especially if it must be multi engine (a.k.a. browser) jitsi also has an safe mobile app you could use instead.

Comment: I didn't ask for one, @ConorMancone. Not sure what makes you think that.

Comment: *"Not sure what makes you think that."* - while the question title seems to ask a generic question about software quality the question body focuses on the quality and your worries about specific software and does not touch the general aspect from the title at all. Even if you did not intend it this way, his makes it look like you want a vetting of this specific software stack or alternatives which are still open-source but less worries. Note that the answer you've accepted explicitly does not address what you asked in the title, so maybe you are not sure yourself what you are asking.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, fair. I'm just not sure how to word it because I was just paranoid about this specific Electron app, but it probably won't be the first desktop app I'll be trying out and having my team try out, and I know product recommendation posts aren't allowed on here. I suppose I could learn pentesting and attempt to find vulnerabilities myself, but the solution I marked gave me good advice which is to just assume that not only apps that I perceive as less-used and thus maybe less eyeball on their code, but any software in general, has vulnerabilities and to use containerization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question stated in the body, not on the title, you could run the wrapper under firejail, or even better, as a snap. Properly done, the application would run with no access to your filesystem, without needing a full VM / container (such as provided by QubeOS).

(note when using snaps, you should still care about updates inside the snap)

Jitsi Meet *does* work with firefox (unless disabled, the server could refuse it service), but Chrome/Chromium does indeed work better with audio/video applications (probably due to the way their javascript and multimedia stack works).

Since you seem to be using some kind of *nix distribution, you probably want to use Chromium rather than Google Chrome (Google Chrome is Chromium plus a few proprietary bits, plus branding). Chromium is probably the one packaged by your distribution. You may still dislike it, but most privacy issues should have been disabled (depending also on the view of downstream about patching and how (un)desirable those 'features' are).

Comment: Yes, I was using Chromium but removed it because I'm using the Electron app now. I didn't see any option to run the app in Firejail or Snap form but maybe that's a separate thing I need to look up how to do. Regarding Firefox, there's a screenshare bug that made us switch back to Zoom until a dev on this site suggested we use Chrom(e/ium), and almost everything was flawless.

Comment: Do you know of a good article explaining the difference, pros and cons of Firejail vs. Snap vs. Docker, etc.? Seems like I can only use the Electron with Firejail, although it doesn't seem technically hard to make a custom (and maybe even community) Snap image.